# How to restrict content and extract data for data analytics

Tags: java, ms-word, ms-wopi

I have gone through the WOPI integration in java. is there any ways to restrict content(Not editable) in the paragraph or finding the placeholder to extract data for analytics.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't restrict content in this way directly in the WOPI editor, but you could use an Add-In or server-side changes to the document (before you provide the document bytes to MS for the first time) to create read-only / undeletable content controls for text.

I think you would need to use an AddIn to extract data analytics.